# Resistance measurement for electrically conductive textile sheet

Tags: electrical-engineering, materials

I have some rolls of coated textile I want to characterize, including some measure of how well the material conducts electricity in the plane of the textile so I can judge which type is least likely to produce electrostatic sparks.

I've found two methods used for measuring surface resistivity or resistance in high-resistance materials.  The first is using a flat plate at either edge of a square sample, where sample size is irrelevant as long as it's square.  This gives resistivity in ohms per square.  This would require me to cut samples and would prohibit in-situ testing of the end-product that this textile is going to be used for.

The second method used a set of needle-point probes to pick random points on a sheet.  First a measurement was taken with 1cm between the probes, and then a second measurement was taken with a 10cm distance between the probes.  The results were not the same, but no explanation was given as to why two measurements were taken or what this technique is useful for.  This technique would be much easier to implement, but I'm not sure if the results are useful or how they should be interpreted.

What's the appropriate measurement method for my application?  Are there any standard procedures for performing the second method I described above?

Comment: How much accuracy do you really need? You can get an ohms per square reading by simply pressing two parallel linear electrodes against the material (spacing equal to their length) that only needs a small correction factor because of the fact that the current isn't entirely contained within the square.

Comment: Ground resistance is measured with 4 equally spaced in-line probes, not sure if this would give surface resistance but I suspect so.  I would make the probes a bit wider than needles so they do not have as much contact resistance variability, perhaps ball ended.

Comment: I'm not convinced that conductivity has much to do with spark possibility.  You get sparks by producing local charge 'blobs' on a physical shape which creates high voltage field strengths.   Electrostatic discharge is easiest to produce with materials that are nearly nonconductive (wool).

Comment: If I had to put a number on accuracy, I'd say maybe within 5-10% is ok.  The real answer is that it has to be enough to determine if any of the textiles is much better or worse than the others.  Do you know what the correction factor is?  Most of the info I can find is directed at 4-point probes and semi-conductor wafers.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid sparks by using a textile that's been treated to improve conductivity.  When something tries to form a charge "blob", the charge is dissipated along the conductive components and no charge "blob" actually forms.  There's no buildup of static electricity that could suddenly discharge in the form of a spark.  So I was working under the assumption that higher conductivity reduces spark possibility - have I missed something?